# Issues with stripe, how to change amount variable depending on item being purchased

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have been trying to implement stripe payments into my webpage but after trying to figure it out for a couple hours i still come up dry. so to start off wat i have so far looks like this

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;

    console.log("print the price "+req.params.name);
    console.log("print the price "+req.params);
    console.log("print the price "+req.body);
    console.log("print the price "+req.params.amount);
    console.log("print the price "+req.body.name);
    console.log("print the price "+req.body.name);
    var amount = req.params.data-amount;

    stripe.charges.create({
        card: stripeToken,
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: amount
    },
    function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        } else {
            res.send(204);
        }
    });
});

<form action="/charge" method="POST">
                            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                data-key="i took this out before i post on stackoverflow"
                                data-image="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/8978785?v=3&s=400"
                                data-name="sfsdfsdfsf"
                                data-description="Send lots to me plz"
                                data-amount="<%=data.price2%>"
                                data-billing-address="true"
                                            data-label="I am poor help me plz"

                                            >
                                    </script>
                                    <p name="<%=data.price2%>"  ></p>
                            </form>
```

so i am trying to place code  in  `var amount=` in the top half of the code.  when i select different items from my catalog the prices being charged should be  dynamic so i dont have to write a charge page for every single item on my catalog. i have a bunch of print statements to try and find the error but i dont know how to deal with object Object outputs. i tried multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
$('#calcTransAmount').click(function(event) {
var amount = $('#transAmount').scope().totall;
//console.log(amount);
var holder = document.getElementById('hello');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
script.setAttribute('class', 'stripe-button');
script.setAttribute('data-amount', amount);
script.setAttribute('data-key',"PUBLIC KEY");
script.setAttribute('data-image', "IMAGE");
script.setAttribute('data-name', "NAME");
script.setAttribute('data-billing-address', "true");
script.setAttribute('data-description', "Purchase");
script.setAttribute('data-locale', "auto");
document.getElementById('btnCont').appendChild(script);
```

});

You need to create the button dynamically to create a dynamic value.